# Switching Between Desktops does not Stick

Tags: osx-lion, workspace, gestures, switching

I am using a MacBookPro and use the three-finger swipe gesture to move between desktops.

However, this feature seems to stop working randomly. Interestingly though, when this happens, I am still able to switch to another desktop by <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>ing to an application that's open in another workspace. But when I do that, I am automatically brought back to the workspace that I was on.

This is a really weird error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is [another distinct symptom of `Dock` glitching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840120/command-left-right-arrow-key-combo-stops-working-after-lion-upgrade) every now and again (as is the loss of <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>). The fix is simple: kill the `Dock` process (it restarts automatically) by doing

```
killall Dock
```

on the terminal (terminal.app can be found using spotlight; it's in /Applications)